# how to absolute position over a jquery slideshow?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and I used a plugin called "meteor slideshows" that I believe is jQuery. I'm trying to absolutely position a widget over the slideshow, however, it is not functioning correctly.

this is my template code:

```
<div class="headersliderarea"> <!-- beginning of placing postitnote --> 
            <div style="clear:both;"><!-- start slideshow --></div><!-- end clearboth -->
<?php if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { meteor_slideshow(); } ?>
    <div class="postitnoteimagearea"><!-- postitnote widget -->
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || 
!dynamic_sidebar('PostItNote') ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- end postitnote widget -->

    </div><!-- end placing postitnote -->
```

I also put the site online over at: http://fortmovies.com/pestcon/

If you look at the homepage where it says "test" is the widget that I am trying to display over the slideshow, which you can't see. you can make it visible if you mess with firebug a little bit I think.

But I have no idea how to display it over the sildeshow.. part of me thinks it's not possible because it's a slideshow php plugin that I'm using to insert it into the template... or maybe I'm missing a simple code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to the closest parent element that also has a defined position I.e. relative, fixed, or absolute.  So in This case you need to define the position of the slides container most likely, and then place your custom element within the container.

You could just wrap a container div around where the plugin gets inserted in the template, and position your element that way, or you could use the structure provided by the slideshow plugin.

Also don't forget about the z-index.  Once inserted into the slideshow container your custom element will need to have the greates z-index value without interfering with any links.  This can get tricky when dealing with positioned elements that overlap, so make sure that when you get it working, all your links and buttons are still clickable.

**Edit 1**
Okay so first of all, your .postitnoteimagearea should have a z-index of 99 or greater.  And I am not too sure that your slideshow plugin is working properly.  It doesn't seem to be appearing.  Even when I messed around with the css, it seems to only show one image that is has a visibility property of "hidden".  Does the slideshow work for you?  Also you don't want to adjust the visibility of the slideshow by giving it a lower z-index value, you simply want to give the element that you want in front of it, a greater z-index value.

Comment: i did this as shown above..... i'm saying the slides disappear when i use the z-index for some reason, you can see my template code above and it's on the website as well.

Comment: that's what i'm saying... it's not appearing. it does work properly, but only when i remove the "z-index" things. but then when i do that, the widget appears behidn it.

Comment: Well, I think at this piont, I would have to say start over.  Get rid of the slideshow, and re-install it with the default CSS, and then work from there knowing what you know now.  There's a good chance that in fiddling with it, you may have changed something that is causing it to be such a problem.  I do it all the time when I come across unique CSS situations.  For now, I would get the slideshow, visible, and working, and start from there.

Comment: dude i was just doing random stuff with the css and did the z index of 100 to the widget and it finally worked.... lol what the hell, why did this work?

Answer (score 0):

CSS. You need to give the widget div a higher z-index than the z-index of the slideshow. A z-index is essentially a layer level, so if the z-index of the slideshow is 1 but the z-index of the widget is 2, the 2 will take precedent over the 1 and be the top layer.

Comment: i did that, but the lower z index (aka the div around the PHP plugin to show the slides), made the slideshow disappear completely.. you can see on the above website where the "test" is, the sildeshow is behind it with a lower z value but it's not showing